# Entity Framework connection string from .udl

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, database-connection, connection-string

I want to change connection string in Web.config file in my ASP.MVC project. Is it possible to set up Entity Framework connection string from .udl? And how?

Answer (score 0):

[I'm assuming you meant to get the connection string with udl, to set it in your web config. not to configure your app with udl file]

Just create new Text Document, and change it to yourfilename.udl.
than open it and configure your connection string. after that open it with notepad or notepad++ and you'll have your connection string ready. copy it to your web.config.